# Join Table In Database Architecture?

Tags: sql, database-design, ms-access-2007, join

I've been working on a database application (Access 2007) and have a couple questions regarding architecture. This is, by far, the most complex application I've written yet.

I presently have 5 tables, each with its own unique ID field:

- platforms
- vehicles
- manuals
- procedures
- faults

It is possible for the same fault to appear in multiple procedures, and for the same procedure to appear in multiple manuals. I would like to provide users the opportunity to copy and delete records, as well as cross-link records between tables.

Presently, I have join tables between each of the tables listed above,

- platforms_vehicles
- vehicles_manuals
- manuals_procedures
- procedures_faults

Editing the relationships between the main tables (by editing contents of the join tables) has gotten quite complicated, as copy and delete actions have a cascading effect on other tables. In my mind, this could be performed efficiently using recursion, but actually getting it to work is another story altogether.

Question #1: Is the architecture I described a "good" way to arrange this data, or is it unnecessarily complicated? (I have a habit of doing things that way.)

Question #2: Is there a "preferred" method of doing this?

Question #3: Would I be better off organizing the tables in a different manner, such as this:

Only 5 tables,

- platforms
- vehicles
- manuals
- procedures
- faults

Each table has a key for its content fields, as well as another key representing its parent record in the next higher table. For example,

- platforms
- platformID, platformName
- vehicles
- platformID, vehicleID, vehicleName
- manuals
- vehicleID, manualID, manualName
- ...

This seems more straightforward to me, and certainly less complex. If you all would care to provide some professional feedback, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: If your tables are one-to-many, like each vehicle is on only one platform, I would skip the join tables for those relationships. Just add a platform id in your vehicle table, and a vehicle id in your manual table. You need the join tables for the lower tables, where it's a many-to-many relationship `Each manual can have many procedures, and each procedure can appear in many manuals`

Comment: Thank you Ghost.  That makes sense to me.  Setting up the table maintenance procedures has become quite the chore.  Do you know of any pre-written navigation class modules I could drop into my application?  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MS Access' Relationship tool to set up Referential integrity rules.  That way, you can cascade deletes and updates automatically.  I would avoid "join tables" as they are unnecessary as long as the parent key is in the table (which would be called a foreign key).

Comment: Join tables are not unnecessary here for the lower level tables, since it is possible `for the same procedure to appear in multiple manuals` and presumably for one manual to contain many procedures.

Comment: Holger - I have the referential integrity rules set as you described. If each table (except the first one) had a key consisting of the parent key field & individual record key field, would that be sufficient to do what the join table would do?

Comment: @ScottChristensen, Yes that should do it.  However, note Ghost's comment.  For example, if a manual has multiple procedures, then you need a child table (or join table as you call it) for the one-to-many relationship.